# getting floating divs to width inside an absolute positioned container container

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on some html/css stuff

I can't seem to get these two floating div's and the footer to be correctly sized inside the parent div.

the content div is positioned absolutely to get header and footer to show respectively.

HTML:

```
<div id="Content">
        <div id="Header">header</div>
        <div id="Container">
            <div id="leftTable">
                <div>left content</div>
            </div>
            <div id="rightTable">
                <div>right content</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Footer">
            <div>footer</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#Content {
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: honeydew;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#Header {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
#Footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: purple;
    height: 70px;
}
#Container {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 70px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
#Container:after {
    clear:both;
}
#leftTable {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
#rightTable {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4CabB/12/
I was hoping to no position the Container div or footer div on the left and right sides and just have it take up the remaining space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit unclear as to what needs to be achieved, but perhaps this solves your issue: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andRyanMiller/4CabB/13/).

Essentially, I just needed to add

```
width: 100%;
```

to your container  to allow its children to take up the space. Parent containers, when absolutely positioned, must have their widths specified.

Comment: I guess this will work I was just hoping that the whole content div could do the padding and not have to worry about padding the header and the footer each.